# How to make line chart with more data in Android in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have to plot a line graph which shows no. of projects in talukas and when clicked on one point it shows more data as shown in this image: [image]

How can I implement that? I tried MPAndroidChart but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: have you checked this link https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView

Comment: And How to put city names on x axis

Answer (score 1):

`MPAndroidChart` provides a class called `MarkerView` to create a `customized popup`. All you need to do is create a custom class that extends the `MarkerView` class as follows:

```
public class MyMarkerView extends MarkerView { 

  private final TextView tvCity;

  public MyMarkerView(Context context, ValueFormatter xAxisValueFormatter) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
     ...
     //bind your TextView contained in the layout over here
     tvCity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
  }

  // runs every time the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update 
  @Override
  public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
     //set your values to the view over here
     tvCity.setText("Some value");
     ...
     super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
  }

}
```

Reference link : [MarkerView](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView)

You can refer this [tutorial](https://www.codeplayon.com/android-bar-chart-with-tooltip-example/) as an example.

Comment: And any idea to change the x-axis values

Comment: @ShaikhFaizan: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982682/set-values-of-xaxis-in-mpandroidchart

Comment: Ok will check that too

Comment: @inkredusk Thank you for the link. it works in my case.